# Advice on learning Remote Sensing software?

Tags: remote-sensing, references

Can you please advice me on which Remote Sensing software ? Which one is popular ? Which one is the least ? Which one is the easy to learn curve ? Pros and Cons welcome ?

Comment: What do you need this software to do? ("Remote sensing" can cover a lot of ground, ranging from creating DEMs from stereo images to multispectral analysis and everything in between.)

Comment: for a dedicated remote sensing stackechange: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59346/remote-sensing

Comment: @whuber - And quite how much ground depends on the altitude, focal length and film format...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find that [ENVI](http://www.exelisvis.com/ProductsServices/ENVI/ENVI.aspx) and [Erdas](http://geospatial.intergraph.com/Homepage.aspx) hold the bulk of the market share for commercial remote sensing software.  You will find that if you are equipped with your favorite GIS software, python and either one of these RS packages, you will be in good shape for RS work.  For the most part, it comes down to personal preference.  However, I have noticed clear differences that may make a difference for you.

**Erdas**

- Warm, fuzzy GUI
- Model building capabilities
- Powerful add-on capabilities such as [Objective](http://geospatial.intergraph.com/products/ERDASIMAGINE/IMAGINEObjective/Details.aspx) for feature
  extraction and [ATCOR](http://geospatial.intergraph.com/products/ERDASIMAGINE/ATCOR/Details.aspx) for atmospheric corrections
- Limited or difficult batch capabilities for many tools

**ENVI**

- [IDL](http://www.exelisvis.com/ProductsServices/ENVI/ENVI/Extensibility.aspx) can be used to extend ENVI functionality and is a powerful
  tool for batch processing
- Excels at processing hyperspectral imagery
- Very good algorithms for classifying vegetation

Given these strengths and weaknesses, I usually stick with Erdas.